# Where is startup.sh for Tomcat8 on Amazon Linux

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, tomcat8

I am not able to locate startup.sh for tomcat8 on Amazon Linux

here are the locations but none contain that file. I want to configure it for jprofiler

```
tomcat8: /usr/sbin/tomcat8 /etc/tomcat8 /usr/libexec/tomcat8 /usr/share/tomcat8
```

My suspect is `/usr/sbin/tomcat8` not sure how I will add these lines (usually I add these files at the end of startup.sh)

```
CATALINA_OPTS="-Xint -agentpath:/home/ubuntu/jprofiler7/bin/linux-linux64/libjprofilerti.so=port=8383 $CATALINA_OPTS"
export CATALINA_OPTS

# end of modifications

exec "$PRGDIR"/"$EXECUTABLE" run "$@"
```